# Google Ads API, conversion action. REMOVE, HIDDEN status cannot be set

Tags: google-ads-api

We started to use Google Ads API V9 instead of Google Adwords API. In Google Adwords API there was status **DISABLED** for the conversion tracker. Now there is **HIDDEN** and **REMOVED** for conversion action. When we try to set **HIDDEN** or **REMOVED** there is an error message:

**REMOVED**-"Enum value 'REMOVED' cannot be used."

**HIDDEN**-"The field's value is on a deny-list for this field."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Right api to use: ConversionActionOperation::setRemove